# Firebase Database Rules: Apply an update only if newData has a child id with user id

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
".write": "auth!=null && (
            (
               newData.val() != data.val() &&
               newData.child('id').val() === auth.uid
            ) 
            || !data.exists()
        )"
```

I'm updating a list element with this schema `{id: {id: id}}` and comparing the id child to `auth.uid` which is the same. For some reason the line returns permission denied.

[image: the error message]

Comment: I think the image brought a better view of the problem but there you go...

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with the rules you've written, the only thing I can think of is that maybe it's a problem with *where* you have those rules. Could you include a little more of your database rules please?

Comment: Please make sure your question includes the JSON that is currently at the location you are trying to update. Also (as Jeremy asked already): make sure the rules are minimal but valid. Right now we have no idea to know where in the rules file you put the snippet that you shared, which could well be the cause of the problem.

Comment: You were both right. I didn't show the whole ruleset for the sake of legibility but it was necessary. The problem was that I thought newData referred only to the changing object, but it seems it wraps all the path that the rule is listening to. So I ended up solving it by adding newData.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

newData actually wraps all the object that is listening to, not just the "new data" that has changed. So I needed to look one level deeper:

```
"chats": {
  "$chat": {
    ".write": "auth!=null && ((newData.val() != data.val() && newData.child('users').child(auth.uid).exists()) || !data.exists())"
  }
}
```